# findViewById not working for specific view

Tags: android, android-layout, findviewbyid

I have an activity loaded from XML, with views having IDs as usual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/white_circle">

            <com.myapp.views.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/price_background">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/priceView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:text="0.1 BTC"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="Bacon Cheeseburger"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I'm trying to reference three views in code:

```
public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    nameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
    priceView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceView);
    imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}
```

`nameView` and `priceView` are referenced correctly, however, `imageView` isn't being referenced and is `null`:

[image]

Why can't I reference `imageView`?

(If I traverse the view tree, it *is* there.)

**UPDATE:** I did both Clean Project and Invalidate Caches/Restart, the problem persists.

**UPDATE 2:** `ItemViewHolder` is derived from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. `CircleImageView` is derived from `FrameLayout` (*not* `ImageView`). This XML is the layout of my view holder.

**UPDATE 3:** Here is my circle view's constructor:

```
public class CircleImageView extends FrameLayout {

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    ...
}
```

Also, as Subzero noted, I've checked the ID property (`mID` field) of the view, and it's `-1`, which seems to be the cause of the problem. I have no idea why it is -1 though.

Comment: try findViewByTag

Comment: @WaleedAsim that would be a workaround, not a solution. I want to know why `findViewById` is not working in the first place.

Comment: Please clean your Project and Rebuild may that issue will be cleared after this.

Comment: Please post your `CircleImageView` class, you might be missing a constructor.

Comment: goto file-->invalidate Cashec/Restart

Comment: Can you check if the CircleImageView that you are initialising is "com.myapp.views.CircleImageView" ? could be the CircleImageview in android support library

Comment: Your code is confusing. Is this XML activity root? Why are you referencing root layout from within a `ViewHolder`?

Comment: @Blackbelt I've updated the question.

Comment: @Pawel the XML is for my view holder. Just added some relevant details to the question.

Comment: In your `CircleImageView` class's two-parameter constructor, are you certain that you're passing the `AttributeSet` in the `super` constructor call?

Comment: @Blackbelt exactly. the XML in the question is inflated in `onCreateViewHolder`.

Comment: there are only one such layout? do you have any similar layout for another screen size or orientation?

Comment: @Subzero yep, only one layout. no other layouts for different traits.

Comment: Replace your custom circle view with regular one and see if issue persists. If yes then post your custom view constructor as @MikeM mentioned..

Comment: may be CircleView changed itself its ID in code like id = View.generateViewId() or something? also you can try to open LayoutInspector and check if this view existed and its id

Comment: @Subzero, yep, found a clue. the `ID` property (`mID` field) of the problematic view is set to `-1` (whereas, say, `nameView` has a perfectly valid positive ID). I have no idea why though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `super` call in your two-parameter constructor to:

```
super(context, attrs);
```

When a `View` is inflated from a layout, the XML attributes and their values are passed into the two-parameter constructor via the `AttributeSet`. If you don't pass that to the superclass, the `id` you've specified in the XML is never set on the `View`, so `findViewById()` won't find it with the given ID.

Comment: That was it. A stupid mistake to forget to call the matching super constructor in the overridden one. Missed that one. Fixing the constructor with the correct args solved the problem.

Comment: Such a life-saver.

Answer (score 1):

I like Use **this** as follows, hope it is helpful.

```
public class CircleImageView extends FrameLayout {

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        this(context,null);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context.attrs,0);
    }

    public CircleImageView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that your imageView in layout.xml is a custom view (com.myapp.views.CircleImageView), not a regular android ImageView.
Try cast to ImageView, if the class extends imageview

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView));
```

or use it as your custom view

```
CircleImageView iv = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView));
```

Comment: **FYI** *Starting with API 26, findViewById uses inference for its return type, so you no longer have to cast.*

Comment: nope, it's not derived from `ImageView`, it's derived from `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu try this as mention in above comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418503/findviewbyid-not-working-for-specific-view#comment89808056_51418503